# Action on both button press and release

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7

I can't get this straight: I have one button that I want one action for the press event and one action for release, I've searched everywhere and can't find an answer.

`KeyDown`, `KeyUp` or `MouseLeftButtonDown` doesn't work with button on windows phone 7.

First I tried combining `GotFocus` and `Click` clickmode release like this:

(As you can see I want Image1 to be shown while pressing button, and hidden when releasing the button)

xaml:

`Button  Click="button1_Click" ClickMode="Release" GotFocus="button1_GotFocus"  Content="byt" Height="72" Margin="0,500,6,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top"`

```
    private void button1_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Image1.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
    }

    private void button1_Click (object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Image1.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
    }
```

This works only one time and could work all the time if I could loose focus from the button when releasing it (tried searching for that as well)

The other thing I tried was changing the clickmode while pressing the button, but didn't get that to work either..

something like this:

```
    private void button1_Click (object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Image1.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;

        button1.SetValue(Button.ClickModeProperty, ClickMode.Release);
        Image1.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
    }
```

(I know that the syntax is wrong somehow in the second one)

Would be grateful for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MouseLeftButtonDown / MouseLeftButtonUp do work on WP7. Obviously not named the best, but they do work on the device.

```
 <TextBlock x:Name="ApplicationTitle" MouseLeftButtonDown="ApplicationTitle_MouseLeftButtonDown" MouseLeftButtonUp="ApplicationTitle_MouseLeftButtonUp"
                   Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"
                   Text="MY APPLICATION" />
```

You'll see Down gets fired, and then immediately Up.

```
 private void ApplicationTitle_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void ApplicationTitle_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {

        }
```

Comment: it doesn't work with button for some reason?? 

I added "object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e" in the functions as you have written...

Comment: But I just realized that I can use a TextBlock instead, thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps all you need is MouseLeftButtonDown/Up.

Answer (score 0):

I used

```
Click="{x:Bind UpArrow_Click}" 
ClickMode="Press" 
PointerCaptureLost="Button_Release"
```

on a button. When button is pressed `UpArrow_Click` event occurs... when button is released Button_Release event occurs